# MySQL InnoDB database restore

Tags: mysql, backup, innodb, restore

I have to restore a database that has been inadvertently DROPped in MySQL 5.0.  From checking the backup files, I only seem to have .FRM files to hold the database data.

Can anyone advise whether this is all I need to perform a database restore/import from the backup, or are there other files I should have to hand to complete this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

.frm files are not the data files, they just store the "data dictionary information" (see [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html)). InnoDB stores its data in ib_logfile* files. That's what you need in order to do a backup/restore. For more details see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-backup.html).

Comment: InnoDB requires the ibdata, ib_logfile*, and/or *.ibd files in addition to the *.frm files.

Comment: what if you only have the ib_logfile* and the .frm files (along with a months old backup)? any chance to recover in that scenario? or do you need the ibdata to recover anything at all?

Answer (score 12):

Restoring innodb:
(assuming your data folder is C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data)

1. Copy the folders of the databases (named after the database name) you want to restore to C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data
2. Copy the 3 ibdata files  to the data folder ex. (C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data)

   > ```
   > _ib_logfile0
   > _ib_logfile1
   > _ibdata1
   > ```
3. Get the size of the _ib_logfile0 in MB (it should be the same as _ib_logfile1) by File Right click -> Properties
4. Edit the mysql config file (mysql\bin\my.ini) for the innodb_log_file_size=343M to be exactly the ibdata files size
5. Run

   > mysqld --defaults-file=mysql\bin\my.ini --standalone --console
   >   --innodb_force_recovery=6
6. Now your data should be back in your database. Export them using phpmysql or any other tool

Comment: doesn't work for me - in phpMyAdmin I can see InnoDb tables, but can't access them

Comment: Step 3/4 unsure if they did anything. Had to remove the files in-order for it to actually restart mysql. 
Unsure what step 5 does... 
But step 1,2,5 and restarted mysql seemed to work!

Comment: Just like @msponagle says. I couldn't complete all the steps but defenetly steps 1, 2, maybe 3 then restart the service and if it wont start try to restart the machine. That worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

The detailed solution you can found here:

http://www.unilogica.com/mysql-innodb-recovery/ (Article in Portuguese)

Besides the flag of **innodb_force_recovery**, I found another solution: **innodb_file_per_table**, that splits InnoDB tables in each file like MyISAM tables.

In a crash recovery you can lost less data than in single file **ibdata1**.