# MySQL InnoDB database restore using .frm files and ibdata files

Tags: mysql, xampp, innodb, recover

Hi mistakenly I have deleted my MySQL database from Windos XP based PC (this database was used to host a Wiki service using Xampp package). Now I am trying to restore the data so that I can atleast retrieve the TEXT entered in the respective table of Mediawiki package.

After deletion I tried to recover the data using Minitool data recovery software and was able to recover the main schema folder containing .frm files, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 and ibdata1 (which was stored under C>xampp>mysql>data).

Now I am trying to restore the database so that I can take a SQL dump and use it accordingly. I have consulted some previous suggestions provided by the experts. Below are the links -

[Restoring MySQL InnoDB files on Windows](http://www.nerdydork.com/restoring-mysql-innodb-files-on-windows.html)

[Stackoverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115681/mysql-innodb-database-restore)

But these did not help me very much, not sure what exactly I am missing from the instructions. At the end I was unable to start MySQL service and it failed with the below errors in log -

```
120823 12:17:04 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
120823 12:17:04 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120823 12:17:04 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
120823 12:17:04 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
120823 12:17:04 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
120823 12:17:04 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120823 12:17:04 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: No valid checkpoint found.
InnoDB: If this error appears when you are creating an InnoDB database,
InnoDB: the problem may be that during an earlier attempt you managed
InnoDB: to create the InnoDB data files, but log file creation failed.
InnoDB: If that is the case, please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-creating-innodb.html
120823 12:17:04 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
120823 12:17:04 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
120823 12:17:04 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
120823 12:17:04 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Any help to recover from this situation will be highly appreciated. I am willing to provide some more data if required. [`MySQL Server Version 5.5, xampp-win32-1.8.0-VC9`]

Comment: Refer this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-creating-innodb.html

Comment: I would do a fresh install of Mysql server in a different folder or server, then copy/overwrite the new .frm and ibdata files with your old ones, and then start the server

Comment: @shubhansh I tried that too but it did not help. Any other suggestions please?

Comment: @golimar Thanks! I tried that too but it did not help. Any other suggestions please?

Comment: Try without copying .frm file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh God finally it's solved :)
Actually I am a novice that's why I could not solve this quickly. Here is the workflow I followed.

- I installed a fresh copy of MySQL server. Run Wizard config for transactional database.
- I stopped MySQL from `Services.msc`
- Then overwrote the `ib* and *frm` files (under the schema folder) in `C/programdata/mysql/mysql` server 5.5/data folder
- Updated the my.ini in `C/apps/mysql` with the `innodb_log_file_size=<actual size of iblogfile0>`
- ran the command `mysqld --defaults-file="C:/apps/mysql/my.ini" --standalone --console --innodb_force_recovery=6`
- once the above completed closed `cmd.exe`
- restarted MySQL service
- Opened MySQL workbench and took a dump

Sorry to confuse you all. Thanks again. Let me know if anybody requires any clarity for the above steps.

Comment: I am following these steps, can you please let me know how much time it will take to complete all these steps? my "ibdata1" file size is 114MB and "ib_logfile0" file size is 5MB.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @techguy4web sorry I dont remember the exact time it took to complete. All I can say it was less than 30 mins most possibly. Good luck!

Comment: ok, thanks for your kind response. my process running since 10 hours on cmd window. How can I know it's running correct or not?
can you help me to inspect this process?

Comment: @techguy4web Unfortunately I solved my problem using a trial and error process. I am not a DB expert. You should seek for some expert help either by asking a new question putting all the details or Googling some existing questions. Sorry to disappoint!