How to Completely Restore a WordPress Site from a Manual Backup
I’ve been (slowly) designing a new WordPress site locally on my Windows 11 hard drive. I’ve been using Apache and MySQL via the XAMPP Control Panel.
I keep running into a situation in which MySQL unexpectedly shuts down. MySQL would run without much incident for a few days. But then it would again shut down unexpectedly. I troubleshooted the problem, tried changing the ports (as many people suggest), etc. But MySQL eventually wound up shutting down again.
Ultimately, I found the most effective way to resolve the MySQL continuing shutdowns, was to completely uninstall, then reinstall XAMPP, including MySQL. But now, I need step by step instructions on how to restore my WordPress site (database, themes and all files) from a local manual backup after XAMPP has been reinstalled.
My backup was made in File Explorer when I copied the entire XAMPP folder and all its contents (including the WordPress files) from the hard drive I’m using as a server to a separate drive. But just copying the WordPress files back to the server drive after reinstalling XAMPP doesn’t seem to restore the site.
Please tell me, step by step, how to restore from my hard drive my WordPress database, all related files and the WordPress theme I had been using.

You would need the backup folder. I have xampp installed and the mysql server stops working regularly. I don’t know the reason, but the most effective method I found (works 99% of the time) is to 1. Go to the xampp/mysql/backup folder. 2. Copy all files and folders except a file called “ibdata1”. 3. Paste them in the xampp/mysql/data folder, overwriting everything. 4. Start the mysql server. It should be fixed.

Yeah, @Klaassiek. I'm in the same boat you're in, as MySQL just stops working for after a week or two... Thanks for your advise; MySQL is working again (for the moment). But I still need to: 1. restore the files, settings and database in the phpMyAdmin panel and 2. restore all the work I did in WordPress: the customized templates, the pages I created, the changes I made via Elementor, etc. How do I restore those? My backups include everything that was in the XAMPP folder, including all the WordPress-related files.

My advice would be to delete the new xampp folder. Replace it with the one from the backup drive. Then follow the procedure as mentioned in my previous comment. (replace the files/folders in data folder with the ones in backup folder except ibdata1)

This answer will tell you how to restore those files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12098668/9131961. As @Klaassiek said, you need some ib* files and some other files too, it's all explained in detail in that answer.

Thank you, thank you, thank you, @Klaassiek. Your last suggestion did just the trick. All my work appears to have been restored and I'm able to continue where I left off without any more fuss. I'm definitely bookmarking this thread with your answer in an easy-to-find place.

Thanks for the link you provided, too, @cabrerahector.
